# How to get an "mouse over" event in kivy

Tags: python-3.x, mouseover, kivy

I am looking for an easy solution, to detect if the mouse(or finger) is an spezific region of a kivy app. The code for that could look like this:

```
BoxLayout:
    Label:
        text: 'box 1'
    Label:
        text: 'box 2'
    Label:
        text: 'box 3'
```

I would like to detect if the cursor or the finger is in box 1, 2 or 3. If the user clicks on the contorl it is easy to handle the "on_touch_xxx" event. But if he is not doing anything I found no good solution.
I have read that it is possible to listen to the "mouse_pos" property. But may be there is another good way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have read that it is possible to listen to the "mouse_pos" property

Yes, do this.

Comment: (Seeing this answer is one year old) Has a built-in "mouseover" event been implemented?

Comment: No, we don't intend to add one by default because it's costly to dispatch frequent events to every widget, and it's trivial to check yourself using mouse_pos. We'd probably accept a contribution for e.g. a MouseOverBehavior that could be combined with existing widgets.